# Which significance test can be used in this instance? - paired, non-normal means

Tags: normality-assumption, count-data, paired-comparisons

I have a data set of behaviours for a herd of captive elephants which I have attempted to quantify to compare for statistical significance, i.e., if a behaviour is performed once during an observation session, a score of 1 is given, if it is performed 4 times in the observation period a score of 4 is given. I have the original data, and have then averaged each behaviour for a period of time before and after an event, giving my paired means and want to compare the two averages to see if there is a significant difference between the two. I originally thought I could just perform a paired t test, however the data doesn't follow a normal distribution, as behaviour is random and so apparently this cannot be applied. Would anyone be able to help or suggest a test to apply to the data.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "averaged each behaviour for a period of time before and after an event"? You have multiple behaviors, right (eg, stamping its foot, spraying water from its trunk, etc)? Did you average all the before behaviors & all the after behaviors into 2 single numbers? What is the event / your substantive hypothesis? Should it have an equivalent effect on every behavior w/o regard for the nature of that behavior?

Comment: sorry yes i had an ethogram of 20 social behaviours, 13 of which were affiliative, 4 were aggressive and 3 were submissive. I marked down each time an interaction was performed between each elephant (5 in the study) for 40, one hour long observation sessions. Unfortunately after 19 hours, one of the elephants passed away very unexpectedly; so I have the average of 19 hours; affiliative, aggressive and submissive behaviour incidence averages over the 19 hours. I want to compare this average, to the 19 hours I recorded after the death, to see if there is any significant change in the amo

Comment: ... any significant change in the amount of social interactions

Comment: the null hypothesis being that there will be no change, and the alternative that there will be a significant change in incidence of behaviours.

Comment: i think i have a poisson distribution, as the events are 'rare'

Comment: Are you averaging affiliative, aggressive & submissive together into 1 number? So the idea is fewer social behaviors of any type, rather than a change in composition? (On a different point, even if the original data were Poisson, the average of Poisson variables wouldn't be Poisson.)

Comment: no I'll have 6 different averages, 2 for each affiliative, submissive and aggressive, with the hope of gaining 3 p values, from the correct test

Comment: so yes sorry a change in composition,

Comment: Can you edit some of this additional information into your question, please?

Comment: The question would probably be easier to understand if you included a selection of your data set.